# Is it possible with constraint layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I have four image views in a constraint layout. My requirement is to show it dynamically by user interaction.

**First time**:

[image]

**Second time : user click on add view**:

[image]

Third time:

[image]

Fourth time:

[image]

when he click on "Remove view" it returned to third, second and first.

**I tried:**

```
Constraint Layout
   |
   |---Parent 4
   |  |--Child View 1
   |  |--Child View 2
   |  |--Child View 3
   |  |--Child View 4
   |--Parent 3
   |  |--Child View 1
   |  |--Child View 2
   |  |--Child View 3
   |--Parent 2
   |  |--Child View 1
   |  |--Child View 2
   |--Parent 1
   |  |--Child View 1
   |
```

XML file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/em_base_color"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/four_image_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/image_seperation_v_four"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/image_seperation_h_four"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview_four"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_right_bottom_four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_seperation_v_four"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_seperation_h_four" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_left_bottom_four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_seperation_v_four"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_seperation_h_four" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_center_four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_seperation_h_four"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/three_image_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/image_seperation_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview_three"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_bottom_three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_seperation_three" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_top_three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_seperation_three"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/one_image_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_center_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.409"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/two_image_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview_two"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_center_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.409"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/two_image_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="two_image_parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/one_image_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="one_image_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/call_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/three_image_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="three_image_parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/four_image_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="four_image_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When user click on add view, show the next view and tried to set images to new view, sometimes it is failing. From [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) I read "No nested view group".

Comment: yes it's completely possible but the question is what have you tried yourself ?

Comment: Yes this is possible. To get better answers show what you have done and explain the "unexpected results".

Comment: You can try with `PlaceHolders` and `ConstraintSet`. By using both will provide you full UI control with better animation handling by default from `ContraintLayout` out of the box.

Comment: @Henry updated question.

Comment: @JeelVankhede  Thank you , I will try and let you know. :)

Comment: @JeelVankhede I tried ConstraintSet ,that works perfectly . Thank you very much.